# Sending a jquery ajax call through visualforce page gives correct data in return,but giving wrong data in lightning component

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app

I have a situation where, when I send an ajax call through visualforce page by adding jquery through

```
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and making ajax call like this :

```
    jQuery.getJSON('https://localhost:44321/Api/SFGetData?callback=?&mType=ad&isRequired=false', function(json){
      console.debug(json.Data);
    });
```

Now when I made a lightning component and added jquery from static resource like this :

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jquery}"
afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" />
```

and then calling ajax request in doInit function like this again :

```
        jQuery.getJSON('https://localhost:44321/Api/SFGetData?callback=?&mType=ad&isRequired=false', function(json){
           console.debug(json.Data);
        });
```

The difference that I am able to find here is that the 1st call which gives correct data has initiator = "jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2" and initiator of 2nd call is : aura_prod.js:15

The initiators were verified from Chrome developer console in Network tab :

Image is posted here : [image: Chrome Developer Console Screenshot]

Comment: https://www.rattanpal.com/2017/09/03/salesforce-make-ajax-calls-lightning-components/

Comment: @gNerb Can this be because I am using jquery 2.2.4?

Comment: It's because you're using jquery at all. Lightning is it's own complicated feature rich framework. Many of the things you want to use jquery for don't work in lightning components such as manipulating the dom. Rather than trying to import a library that you are comfortable with, you need to learn how to use the libraries provided by SFDC.

Comment: Ok, but in my calls i have to send callback parameter to server and jquery handles it for me, how can i send callback from xmlhttprequest?

Comment: jquery is just a library built on top of JS if jquery can do it you can do it too. Just google for some help. You can also ask questions like that on stackoverflow.com

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery This post says that all you have to do is set  `httpRequest.onreadystatechange` to a function before calling `httpRequest.send()`

Comment: you could try to put the version of you lightning component to v39 or lower. then there is no locker services active and you might get better results. For me is doing simple things without jquery frequently turns just into a huge waste of time. In plain vanilla JS stuff done with jquery in one line usually becomes very verbose and hard to read and maintain.